# Audio File Path On Android Device

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-resources, android-audiomanager

I have an mp3 file on my *Galaxy S6* called `song`. I have a simple app with one `Button` that when clicked, I'd like my song file to play.

How can I get the path of that song and assign in to my `MediaPlayer` object?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a step by step short tutorial:

- 1st - Create a "raw" directory in your res folder.
- 2nd - Put your mp3 file inside that directory (res/raw/mySong.mp3).
- 3rd - In your onCreate method put the following code:

  ```
  MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.mySong);
  mp.start();
  ```

If you want to access an external file:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/Music/mySong.mp3")););
mp.start();
```

And ofc, don't forget the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I actually meant the file that's already on my phone. I'm looking for a way to access the mp3 I have stored on my phone VS creating a res/raw folder and having them in Android. I have no idea how to reach them on my actual device.

Comment: That's awesome, I have one more quick follow up, the App is crashing due to an "Execution Exception getting info from device," which makes me think that my file path is wrong to my actual song aka the last piece of the code you showed me. Is there a universal file path that reaches the audio library on the device? Right now my mp3 file is called song and I am calling it like this "/sdcard/song" So here's how the entire thing looks in the IDE :  mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/sdcard/song"));

Comment: Have u added the permissions to access the external storae?

Comment: No I haven't it yet. I found this online:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> Is that correct and does it go in my manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

I made a short video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6-y4Ecuo2WQ&t=1s) showing how you can set a piece of audio already stored on your phone to a MediaPlayer object. Hope it helps.